# maximal algebraic degree of a balanced Boolean functions

Tags: functions, cryptography

While I was studying some cryptography maths, about balanced boolean functions i felt in a proposition that says

```
"The maximal algebraic degree of a balanced Boolean 
 functions of n variables is n − 1"
```

Why is this true??

Comment: What's the definition of *balanced*? It attains both values equally often?

Comment: If so, then it immediately follows that degree $n$ cannot be achieved, because degree $n$ Boolean functions in $n$ variables attains value $1$ (=True) an odd number of times, so cannot be balanced. To prove the claim, it would then suffice to exhibit a balanced boolean function of degree $n-1$.

Comment: thats a true answer you should post it as an answer!! thanks:)

Comment: Thanx for the answer. The only thing i am missing is why degree n Boolean functions in n variables attain True value an odd number of times. Can you post an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let True $=1$ and False $=0$ as usual. The addition of Boolean functions is XOR, so equivalent to addition modulo two.

When there are $n$ Boolean variables, call them $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$, we see that any **monomial** function $x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_k}$, $1\le i_1<i_2\cdots<i_k\le n,$ of degree $k$ evaluates to True exactly $2^{n-k}$ times: those $k$ variables must all be true, but we can pick the truth values of the other $n-k$ variables as we wish. We observe that this is an even number, iff $k<n$.

Another key observation is that if $p(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $q(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ are Boolean functions such that they both evaluate to True an even number of times, then so does there sum $p+q$. This is because if $p$ evaluates to True $\ell$ times, $q$ evaluates to True $m$ times, and they both evaluate to True simultaneously $s$ times, then $p+q$ evaluates to True $(\ell-s)+(m-s)=\ell+m-2s$ times.
If both $\ell$ and $m$ are even this is an even number proving the claim. Also observe that if exactly one of $p$, $q$ evaluates to True an odd number of times, then so does there sum.

From these two observations we get by induction on the number of terms that any polynomial of degree $\le n-1$ evaluates to True an even number of times. We also
conclude that any polynomial of degree $n$ evaluate to True an odd number of times. This is because a polynomial of degree $n$, say $p$, can be written as 
$$
p(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=q(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)+x_1x_2\cdots x_n,
$$
with $\deg q<n$. Therefore no Boolean function of degree $n$ is balanced, when $n>1$ (a trivial exception is, when $n=1$, so let's assume that is not the case).

To complete the claim we need to prove the existence of Boolean polynomial of degree $n-1$ that is balanced, i.e. evaluates to True exactly $2^{n-1}$ times.
We can do this recursively. When $n=2$ the polynomial $p_2(x_1,x_2)=x_2$ works,
and when $n=3$, the polynomial $p_3(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1+x_1x_3+x_2x_3$ works.
Assume that $n\ge3$ and that we have found a balanced polynomial
$p_n(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ of degree $n-1$. Let us define
$$
p_{n+1}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}):=p_n(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)x_{n+1}+x_1(1+x_{n+1}).
$$
I claim that this works. Here the first term is obviously of degree $(n-1)+1=n$, and the second term is of degree $2<n$, so there cannot be a cancellation of the highest degree terms, and thus $\deg p_{n+1}=n$. The presence of the complementary factors, $x_{n+1}$ and $(1+x_{n+1})$, means that the two terms never evaluate to True simultaneously. OTOH, either of the two terms evaluates to True $2^{n-2}$ times, the former by the induction hypothesis (when $x_{n+1}=1$), the latter by a direct observation (when $x_{n+1}=0$). Therefore $p_{n+1}$ is balanced, and we're done.

Comment: What is meant by algebraic degree here? Isn't the parity on two variables $x_1 x_2$ a balanced function of degree two? (Representing the Boolean constants as $\pm 1$, but degree should be independent of that.)

Comment: @gen $x_1x_2$ is not balanced. With both $x_1$ and $x_2$ ranging over $\{0,1\}$ it takes the values $1$ only once, and $0$ thrice.

Comment: That's interesting; if you take it as a function on $\{\pm 1\}^2$ then it is balanced: $(1)(1) = (-1)(-1) = 1$ and $(-1)(1) = (-1)(1) = -1$, so seems like that while the degree is invariant w.r.t. representation of constants, the function being balanced is not.

Comment: @gen I think that using $\{0,1\}$ here is standard. $\{\pm1\}$ is used when we move from additive domain to a multiplicative one. How would you treat the sum (=XOR)  and product (=AND) of boolean functions in the multiplicative representation?

Comment: The $\pm$-based formulation is primarily used in the context of the Fourier analysis of Boolean functions (c.f. O'Donell's textbook). I'm not sure I understand your question: if you are asking about expressing these functions in the other representation, you can always translate the Boolean variables by invertible linear maps, e.g. $1-2x_i$ from $\{0,1\}$ to $\{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: @gen That's what I meant, too. Fourier-analysis (also known as Walsh or Walsh-Hadamard transformation) is an indispensible tool here. My question was: how do you map $x_1x_2+x_3x_4$ into the $\pm1$ domain. In other words, the boolean function ($x_1$ AND $x_2$) XOR ($x_3$ AND $x_4$)? Anyway, I prefer to write the mapping $x\mapsto (-1)^x$ rather than $x\mapsto 1-2x$ when going from $\{0,1\}$ to $\{\pm1\}$. This is very useful for the purposes of studying the Walsh-Hadamard transformation (e.g. in the context of bent functions).